# Does posting short memorable scenes or songs from a movie constitute copyright violation?

Tags: copyright

On Youtube I often see videos of songs or other short memorable scenes from various movies posted. Since these are non-transferable I assume this is technically a violation of copyright, even if it's done for a very popular movie.

Is it a violation of copyright to post or watch such clips?

Comment: What do you mean by "these are non-transferable?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use of copyrighted material without license is not considered infringing if it complies with the proscriptions of [fair-use](/questions/tagged/fair-use), which are [enumerated by both statute and case law](http://copyright.gov/fair-use/).  Without a specific example one couldn't guess whether or which fair-use exemption might apply.